# Problems with a large number of migrations in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

We have large number (about 735) of migrations in our project. In some of them, we have made manual changes. How we can convert them to single file or decrease the number of them? We cant remove migrations and add a new migration to make them a single file, because we will lose manual changes that we do in migrations.

[image: Solution of project]

Comment: What kind of manual changes do you have?

Comment: we have manual Events and some ‎ interface Classes

Answer (score 1):

> (we cant remove migrations and Add a new migration for make them to a single file ,because we will lost manual changes that we do in migrations).

That *is* the method. You shouldn't be making manual changes to the migrations, in the first place, and this is one reason why. You either go code-first, and generate migrations from your code (only) or you go database-first, and scaffold the code based on the database. You're trying to do some hybrid, where you're making changes to the database that aren't being reflected in your code, and that's bad design.

Comment: I believe sometimes you are forced to make manual changes to migrations, like for me to set `NO CACHE` on sequences or if you want to use stored procedures.